# Merge different Data Extensions without a common value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, query, dataextensions

I have two different Data Extensions that I would like to merge together.

I have on one side the Subscribers data and on other side voucher code table.

I would like to assign to every customer automatically with a query a voucher code but I don't have any common field to merge it.

Comment: Do you want to include all the fields in two DE into one DE

Comment: Hi @Josyula, thanks for replying. I would like to call only one field (email_address) from Subscribers and only (voucher_code) from the table voucher so I can run an AMP Script. Do you have any suggestions? 'Thanks a lot.

Comment: My thoughts: Create another DE and pull the data from that two DE using queries and dump those fields data into the DE that you newly created. Did You try this??

Comment: Hi Josyula, I already tryed and it's not working because the datas are not on the same row: es. email xx@xx.xx and voucher code is empty and I have other rows with voucher_code xxxx and email empty

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a solution in AMPScript, the [**ClaimRow()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/claimrow4/) AMPScript function is what you want.

Here's how I typically claim coupons for a subscriber:

```
%%[

var @em, @couponRow, @couponCode, @rows, @row

/* include your sendable attribute/column here */ 
set @em = AttributeValue("emailAddr") 

set @rows = LookupRows("couponCodes","EmailAddress",@em)

if rowcount(@rows) > 0 then
  set @row = Row(@rows,1)
  set @couponCode = field(@row,"couponCode")
else

    if _messagecontext == "PREVIEW" then
           set @couponCode = "XX TEST XX"
    else

      set @couponRow = ClaimRow("couponCodes","IsClaimed","EmailAddress",@em) 

      if empty(@couponRow) then
         /* You can do other error handling here if you want.*/
         /* This aborts the send */
         raiseError("no more coupons available")
      else 
         set @couponCode = field(@couponRow,"couponCode") 
      endif

    endif 

endif

]%%

Here's your coupon code: %%=v(@couponCode)=%%
```

I have a more details here on my blog: [**Coupon Claiming in AMPScript**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/coupon-claiming-in-ampscript/)

**UPDATE**

If you wanted to just mach emails to voucher codes, you can generate a key to use in your JOIN between the two DEs.  In this case, just assigning a `row_number()` for both.

```
select
s.emailaddress
, s.subscriberkey
, v.voucherCode
from (
    SELECT 
        [emailaddress]
        , [subscriberkey]
        , row_number() over (order by emailaddress) emailRanking
    FROM [testSubscribers] 
) s
inner join (
  select 
  voucherCode
  , row_number() over (order by voucherCode) voucherRanking
  from [testVouchers] 
) v on (v.voucherRanking = s.emailRanking)
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for the answer. I already checked this topic before but here seems that I need to have the field "Email_address" inside the Coupon Data Extension in order to run the "Lookup".

Comment: So?  If you're doing an email send, you'll have it.  Wouldn't you want to know what vouchers are assigned?

Comment: Hi Adam, the problem that I have is not related to the coding but on data extension, as I mentioned before. I would like to push via Query datas from both tables in one (subscribers + voucher code) in order  to asign automatically inside the new data extension the voucher to each user.

Comment: For example I have those emails: abc@abc.com, def@abc.com, ghi@abc.com and another table with those coupons XX123, XX124, XX125. I would like to push those datas in a data extensions in order to asign the first VC to the first user imported.

Comment: What's the reason for pre-assigning the vouchers?

Comment: It's because then I don't need to do always export of subscribers from each BU and it's related mostly to use for triggered emails like a Welcome Email.

Comment: Exporting subscribers from each BU??  You lost me.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a query that'll match the emails and vouchers.  The matching is done sequentially having both email and vouchers ordered alphabetically.  Still not sure why you'd ever want to do it this way.  There's no way to prevent re-use or to keep track of who was assigned what voucher code.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your comment. For BU I was meaning Business Unit. I used your query and I modified the fields with the rights table name and field name but is not working. What I thought also was to create an Customer_ID inside the Subscribers Table that is actually the row's number.